# Nuget package copy file to local using powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am working on a Nuget package which should copy files to Users C drive. How can I write powershell script and where should I place file in nuget content folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the conventional powershell scripts as documented [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal).

The most appropriate place for your files is probably in the "tools" directory of the package, as documented [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory).

Comment: I have folder abc.zip. I want to place this in users visual studio templates folder. My question is while creating package, where should I place this folder and in powershell script what source path should I give? my code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417287/nuget-powershell-script-source-and-destination-path-issue